# SQLite Database Dump and Read Functions Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am relatively new to using SQLite on Android. I have some experience with SQLite in the windows command prompt. Is there anyway to use the .output, .dump, .mode, .read, and other native commands of sqlite directly in you Javacode for android? I know there is a db.exec(raw SQL command) in android, but you can only execute non return tasks like inserting a row.

I ideally would like to be able to export a query of my SQLite database to a text file or .csv file directly on the phone without having to manually query the database and do the string formatting then output write the file. I know this is possible within the command prompt on a sqlite db on a computer.

```
>.ouput file.csv
>.separator ,
>select * from test;
```

then you have file in the directory of your db that is called file.csv with the results of the select query. **Can I do the same thing directly with sqlite in an Android activity?** (I do not mind having to then move the file.csv to the sd card for the user to get it etc and am comfortable doing that part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to use the .output, .dump, .mode, .read, and other native commands of sqlite directly in you Javacode for android?

No, because there is no guarantee that there is a SQLite command-line client on your device. The things you list are not "native commands of sqlite", but are native commands of a **`sqlite3`** command-line binary.